# Assume that there are 101 nodes in a Raft cluster. Then, to succeed an operation, how many responses are required in the cluster?

Tags: raft

I know that the leader's response is required, but are other nodes required to respond in order for the operation to succeed?

Comment: What do you get by applying the quorum rule? (Remember that the leader is in the quorum.)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what do you mean with "leader's response". Leader accepts a request from a client and sends a response to the client when a new log entry is committed. It is totally possible that the request is committed, but the communication has failed to notify the customer. In that case the customer does not actually know the outcome, the they should act accordingly.

To under the question in the title: raft original paper (https://raft.github.io/raft.pdf) is pretty clear on that: "A log entry is committed once the leader
that created the entry has replicated it on a majority of
the servers " [5.3]. In other words, majority has to accept the new entry for it to be accepted, which is equivalent to "operation succeeded".

Actually the leader response is not required for a record to be committed to the log. Leader